# Is it safe to send credit card details securely over http POST using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, http, payment

The API that I'm using requires me to send Credit Card Details to complete payment through a HTTP POST request (through swift). Is this safe by any means? And moreover, how do I securely store credit card information for repeated payments?

The credit card holder's name, credit card number, cvc, and date of expiry are all sent over a POST request. Then, the API returns whether the payment was successful, and the last four digits of the credit card number.

Simply put, I'm not entirely familiar with payment security, and would like to know if this is safe, and moreover how to save payment information securely using swift, even if that's possible. I don't think I can use stripe for this process, but I would love to know if that's possible as well.

**EDIT:**
I have confirmed that the API I'm using does in fact employ an HTTPS connection, and not simply a HTTP server. At this point, I know not to save credit card information locally and that I should retrieve it from a third party service before handling it. Thanks All!

Comment: Answer is no, sending credit card details over HTTP is very *insecure*, time to start looking for a better provider of API that **must** insist on sending data securely over HTTPS and that the certificate is verified. In short, you are putting users into a position of risk and is highly irresponsible to do so.

Comment: Sending ***anything*** over http is insecure.

Comment: You don't say what payment API you're using but your job is to handle the credit card info as little as possible. Never store it on a device or on your own server. Payment APIs might also give you back a token or ID to identify that card for future use along with last four digits to show your user in case you want to allow user to pay for something else using the same card later. Never store that information anywhere yourself, and only transmit it via secure (httpS) connections that one time.

Comment: I haven't chosen a payment API yet. All I would need to do is have to save cc information that then I can retrieve to send over a https request to this other API. Would stripe work for something of that nature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append a 's' with your http then it's permissible. http is insecure as already mentioned by @t0mm13b. So it's not safe.

there is a [Nice post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48368/credit-card-information-being-sent-over-http).

**Edited:**

Don't be just happy that appending 's' is sufficient though. :)

Comment: just appending an `s` is not enough, the server might only support http.

Comment: @luk2302: Of course.And it's a must. And i have edited my answer so that none can be happy by doing that. :)

Comment: thanks so much! And, alright, let's assume that I'm able to confirm the API & server does in fact have HTTPS capability. Once that's secured, how I would save the cc information using swift for repeated payments?

Comment: if this answer is helpful i hope you accept it too.:)

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift or any other programming language and sending sensitive information over `HTTP` is not secure as mentioned in the comments.

Instead you should use an `HTTPS` connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sending any sensitive information over HTTP is not secure and not recommended. Most of the payment gate ways doesn't allow you to establish a session on HTTP. Even if you are using HTTPS usually sensitive information is encrypted and sometimes encoded on client end and server decrypts, decodes and processes it which inturn gives double security to the requests you make.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things absolutely clear:

#### The answer is NO. Even *if* one is using https!

While HTTPS encryption may satisfy some legal requirements, it's generally advisable to encrypt sensitive data like credit card numbers on the client side as well to ensure maximum protection and compliance with relevant laws and standards.

Since your case involves an API to which you reach out to... you have no choice. But I still wanted to state this fact about https not being entirely secure, so that others who may stumble upon this thread know the whole story and be aware of the risks.